# Pin element to bottom of another element via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I have been running through issue, and my calculations seem to be off at some where, but for the life of me I can't figure out where.

Basically, what I am trying to do is have an element that is pinned to the inside of another element. So on scroll the pinned element will reside at the bottom of the user's viewport until it hits the end of its container parent.

I know that there is the [jQuery Pin](http://webpop.github.io/jquery.pin/) plugin out there...but I would like to build it myself so I can integrate into another plugin — *plus learning purposes*.

Below is my basic calculations, and there is a fiddle to see it more in tune with what I want to accomplish.

```
var $win = $(window);

$win.on('scroll', function(e) {
    var $base = $('.base'),
        $inner = $('.inner'),

        baseoffset = $base.offset().top,
        viewportHeight = $win.height(),
        innerBoundingBox = $base[0].getBoundingClientRect().top,

        innerPOS = innerBoundingBox + viewportHeight; 

    if(innerPOS < 0) {
        $inner.css('bottom', 0); 
    } 
    else {
        $inner.css('bottom', innerPOS);
    }
});
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/listao/Acb6R/

**Update:** jsFiddle link updated to latest revision.

Comment: Fiddle code doesn't seem to be an example of the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that, I must of not set the new changes as the base. I will update the link. Thanks!

Comment: missing a semi colon in your fiddle css for ...color: red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've calculated the top of your box, but not the bottom. Here's a solution:

```
var $win = $(window),
    $base = $('.base'),
    $inner = $('.inner');

$win.on('scroll', function(e) {
    var viewportHeight = $win.height(),
        baseBoundingBox = $base[0].getBoundingClientRect().top,
        innerPOS = (baseBoundingBox + $base.outerHeight()) - viewportHeight,
        baseWidth = $base.outerWidth();

    if(innerPOS <= 0) {
        if ($inner.css('position') !== 'absolute') {
            $inner.css({ position: 'absolute', maxWidth: 'none', left: 0, marginLeft: 0 });
        }
    } 
    else {
        if ($inner.css('position') !== 'fixed') {
            $inner.css({ position: 'fixed', maxWidth: baseWidth, left: '50%', marginLeft: -(baseWidth / 2) });
        }
    }
});
```

I'm changing the `position`, width, and centering info. Kind of a hassle, but since `.inner` is a child of `.base` (which is `position: relative`) I can't think of a better way.

Here's the fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/rodgolpe/Acb6R/7/

Comment: Rodney, thanks for the reply! That seems to be working pretty great. My only question is how would I limit the upper bound of the "inner" element say to 200px from the top of the "base" element? `innerPOS > baseBoundingBox.top + 200`?

Comment: So you would hide `.inner` until at least 200px of `.base` is visible?

Comment: Yes, basically :). Just so `.inner` is not covering up any headers, etc.. if the user scrolls beyond the top. Thanks again for the concise response and solution thus far. I still have to study your solution for why you used the properties that you did (`maxWidth`, 'marginLeft`, etc...).

Comment: Ok, that's a test you have to do before considering the value of `innerPOS`. I updated the fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/rodgolpe/Acb6R/9/. Basically, you need to check whether `baseBoundingBox <= viewportHeight - 200`. I applied a fade effect, but you can also just toggle `display: block` and `display: none`.

Comment: The reason I changed `maxWidth`, `left`, and `marginLeft` is because when you set an element to `position: fixed` it fills the entire width of the screen. I wanted to keep the width of `.inner` the same as `.base` and to keep it centered.

Comment: Wow, that answers most of my questions. Thanks again for the clear, and easy to understand responses. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Sure thing! Good luck with your project.